# pandas how to split single row into multiple row based on comma and remove 3rd bracket and single quotation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame like this where I have multiple image in a single row for every product.

```
link           https://shopnox.com/collections/all/products/s...
image          ['//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2149/0521/produc...
title                         SLIQUID ORGANICS NATURAL ALOE LUBE
price                                                       $10
```

I want to split multiple row based on comma and also want to remove 3rd bracket and single quote of image row. I tried this but didn't work

```
data['image'].replace("[]'", '') #I added single quote inside double quote because I also want to remove  single quote
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `str.split` with `explode` and `mask`:

```
data['image'] = data['image'].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'", '').str.split(',')
data = data.explode('image')
data['price'] = data['price'].mask(data['price'].shift() == data['price'])
print(data)
```

Comment: not working getting this error ` File "<unknown>", line 1
    //cdn .shopify .com /s /files /1 /2149 /0 521 /products /sona .png ?v =1597423005 ', '//cdn .shopify .com /s /files /1 /2149 /0 521 /products /IMG_8128 -1_2_1. png ?v =1622204799
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: U12-Forward now getting this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @boyenec Oh my bad sorry, should work now

Comment: U12-Forward Thanks. it's removing 3rd bracket and single quote but not splitting multiple row based on comma.

Comment: U12-Forward is it possible to split image row into multiple row based on comma. I have multiple product image url in image column.

Comment: @boyenec That is another silly error from my end, should work now!

Comment: Thanks a loooot...it's worked. Would you mind if I ask one more question? Is it possible  to extend only image and product  title row? Right now it's extending with all column. Is it possible to extend with few specific column ?

Comment: @boyenec DO you mean by setting `price` column to `NaN` on other rows?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want it will extend with only image and prdouct title column but keep empty row for others column.

Comment: U12-Forward getting this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` I have multiple row should I TRY THIS??? `data['price','description'] = data['price','description'].mask(data['price','description'].diff().eq(0)) `

Comment: @boyenec Edited my answer try now, this should work now

Comment: greate :). it worked. should I try somethings like this for multiple column `data['price','description'] = data['price','description'].mask(data['price','description'].shift() == data['price'])`??? Thanks again. I am using this for mutiple row `data['price'] = data['price'].mask(data['price'].shift() == data['price'])
data['link'] = data['link'].mask(data['link'].shift() == data['link'])
data['title'] = data['title'].mask(data['title'].shift() == data['title'])`

Comment: U12-Forward Thanks a loooooooooot. God bless you:)))) You help me loooot